# Inlude javascript files or apply javascript functions on items loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, smarty

So here is the problem I'm struggling with - I have implemented an infinite scroll for comments on my website, but every comment requires a lot of javascript functions for styling, interactivity and etc (also every comment can be open in bootstrap modal). Opening the page with article and getting first few comments in regular way is fine, but when user start scrolling down and get new comments javascript is working. I've realized that this is happening do to the absence of included javascript files in my ajax.tpl file.
Here is the structure of my files and examples on how does it works:
(I'm using smarty as a template but I don't think it makes big difference now, it just allows to divide logic code from html.)

I have `article.tpl` where all my comments are showing up, also I have `ajax.php` where new comments are retrieved from database, and `ajax.tpl` with html code to show comments in `article.tpl`. Here is the JS function I'm using to trigger loading of new comments:

```
//Infinite scroll
flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
    first = $('#first').val();
    limit = $('#limit').val();
idt = $('#idt').val();
    no_data = true;
    if(flag && no_data){
        flag = false;
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
            data: {
               start : first,
               limit : limit,
       idt : idt
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                flag = true;
                $('#loader').hide();
                if(data !=''){

                    first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                    limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());
                    $('#first').val( first+limit );
                        $('#timeline-container').append( data );

                }else{
                    alert('No more data to show');
                    no_data = false;
                }
            },
            error: function( data ){
                flag = true;
                $('#loader').hide();
                no_data = false;
                alert('Something went wrong, Please contact admin');
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

All my js files are included in the bottom of every template file, I tried to include js files in `ajax.tpl` but this leads to lots of mistakes due to the multiple includes. Will be really happy on any advise or help! Thanks everyone!

Comment: The first step is to build these as two separate concepts.
If your thinking is that you're going to build some HTML in PHP, and you're going to write some JS to deal with that, then you will come up with very different solutions than if you are thinking about being on a page that came from the server, whether it was done in Laravel, Express, ASP.net, et cetera, but now that you are on the page, you have to work in your own box.

Basically, learn to treat client code as its own program, and its own services, and not as a helper script that gets injected into the page, and it will hurt less.

Comment: You should debounce your scroll handler function, meaning that it fires once only after the user stops scrolling for a while: (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) Otherwise the handler will be executed tens or hundreds of times per second.

Comment: Thank for the debounce hint, but as I can understand it won't help me with my issue now? Anyway, I was going to implement some piece of code to stop calling ajax php file when there is no more comments, if this is what `debounce` is about...

Comment: You've mentioned that you have your JS at end of every TPL ? wouldn't it cause duplicate of the same code in the same page? and can you post the content of .tpl and .php file?

Comment: No, you're right that was just meant as a comment. It's really difficult to understand what is going on without seeing your actual code. What does the dynamically loaded JS do exactly? Is it different for each request? If not, then why not load the needed script just once?